# Perl check if a string contains mysql timestamp

Tags: perl

I have a variable $data that may or may not contain a mysql timestamp. I want to check if it actually contains a timestamp or not.

```
$data = '2015-11-21 13:45:20';
```

I can probably check it using a big regex like

```
/2[0-9][0-9][0-9]-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]) ([01][0-9]|2[0-4]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/
```

But is there an easier way ?

Comment: Would it not be enough to just check the rough structure? Maybe like `/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/`?

Comment: What else can it contain?

Comment: @MattJacob yeh that will probably work as well. But, I was wondering if there's any BIF for that.

Comment: @choroba it can contain timezone info like Asia/Hongkong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Perl module DateTime::Format::MySQL. Its `parse_datetime` method will throw an exception if the input format isn't acceptable, or will return a DateTime object if it can be parsed as a MySQL datetime.  It seems to be pretty strict, which may be what you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime::Format::MySQL;

while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    print "$_: ";
    my $result = validate_date($_);
    print defined $result
        ? "Recognized format. ($result)\n"
        : "Unrecognized format.\n";
}

sub validate_date {
    return eval {DateTime::Format::MySQL->parse_datetime(shift)};
}

__DATA__
2015-11-21 13:45:20
2015-11-21 13 : 45 : 20
```

With a DateTime object, and in particular, with the DateTime::Format::MySQL module it's pretty easy to turn around and output MySQL-ready datetime strings.

On the other hand, if the goal is to accept input, validate it, and then send it out to MySQL, you might consider using the `parse_datetime` method from DateTime::Format::DateParse to accept as wide a variety of date strings as practical. That module returns a DateTime object. Then you can use the DateTime::Format::MySQL method, `format_datetime` to convert that DT object to a useful MySQL format.  That way you are being liberal in what you accept, but strict in what you output, which is often a reasonable design pattern.